# Duplicate options aren't displayed nicely on Chrome for Android:

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, close-dialog, android, mobile-chrome

Duplicate options aren't displayed nicely on Chrome for Android:

[image]

It is clearer when viewed on Chrome for Microsoft Windows:

[image]